Filtering a List with other two Lists
Consider the following three example lists:
List<string> localPatientsIDs = new List<string> { "1550615", "1688", "1760654", "1940629", "34277", "48083" };

List<string> remotePatientsIDs = new List<string> { "000-007", "002443", "002446", "214", "34277", "48083" };

List<string> archivedFiles = new List<string>{
    @"G:\Archive\000-007_20230526175817297.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\002443_20230526183639562.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\002446_20230526183334407.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\14967_20240703150011899.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\214_20231213150003676.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\34277_20230526200048891.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\48083_20240214150011919.zip" };

Please note that each element in archivedFiles is the full path of a ZIP file, whose name begins with the patientID that is either in localPatientsIDs or remotePatientsIDs.
For example: @"G:\Archive\000-007_20230526175817297.zip" : the filename 000-007_20230526175817297.zip initiate with 000-007, which is an element in the list remotePatientsIDs.
A patientID connot be at localPatientsIDs and archivedFiles simultaneously, therefore, no duplicates are allowed between these two lists. However, the archivedFiles can contain patientIDs that are also located in remotePatientsIDs.
I need to get the elements in archivedFiles whose file names begin with the elements present in remotePatientsIDs but not present in localPatientsIDs. The endpoint is to Unzip those files to the directory that contains localPatientsIDs database.
For the given example, I would expect to have the following result:
archivedFilesToUnzip == {
    @"G:\Archive\000-007_20230526175817297.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\002443_20230526183639562.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\002446_20230526183334407.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\214_20231213150003676.zip" }

So, how can I use LINQ to do this ?
In my lack of knowledge, I would expect it to be as simple as:
List<string> archivedFilesToUnzip = archivedFiles.Where(name => name.Contains(remotePatients.Except(localPatients)))

I cannot even compile this, since Contains probably is unable to iterate over the List members and I get the message:
CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'
Then my best trial so far is the following sentence (I confess it seems a little messy to me). It always returns an empty list.
List<string> archivedFilesToUnzip = archivedFiles.Where(name => archivedFiles.Any(x => x.ToString().Contains(remotePatients.Except(localPatients).ToString()))).ToList();

I've found these helpful posts that helped me to better understand the differences between Where and Select :

Difference between Select and Where in Entity Framework and
Linq: What is the difference between Select and Where

Also, I've been looking for any directions using LINQ on :

Filter Out List with another list using LINQ
Filter a list by another list C#
Filter a list based on another list condition

and other links as well, but I still cannot find a working solution.

It is worth noting that both answers below first extract the Patient ID from the file name and then check for matches, rather than to attempt to match the whole file path using a test like .Where(filename => missingPatientsIDs.Any(pid => filename.Contains(pid). The latter can lead to false matches like a PID being found in the folder path or timestamp, or a partial match like 000-007 matching 1000-0071.

Thank you @TN for your important consideration! Just to confirm, when you say "The latter can lead to false matches" you refer to the Contains method, right?
.Where(filename => missingPatientsIDs.Any(pid => filename.Contains(pid)

Yes. That is correct. string.Contains() allows a partial match, which can produce false matches. The answers below use collection.Contains(), which is a different animal that requires exact matches.

C# is statically (and mostly strongly) typed language (see the What is the difference between a strongly typed language and a statically typed language? question and The C# type system article if you want to dive deeper). It means that compiler will check variable types and will not allow a lot of mistakes like comparing string and boolean.
remotePatients.Except(localPatients) is a collection of string's while name in archivedFiles.Where(name => name is "just" a string. Contains on string can accept either char (a symbol in a string) or another string, not a collection of strings, hence the compilation error.
Your second attempt compiles, but will not achieve anything meaningful - if you assign remotePatients.Except(localPatients).ToString() to a variable and examine it or print the result to console you will see just the type name (System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__991[System.String]` to be exact) which obviously is not part of the file name.
As for your question, I would suggest to do the following:
// build the diff hashset for quick lookup for ids to add
// will improve performance if there are "many" ids
var missing = remotePatients.Except(localPatients)
    .ToHashSet();

// regular expression to extract id from the file name
// you can implement this logic without regex if needed
var regex = new Regex(@"\\(?<id>[\d-]+)_\d+\.zip");

// the result
List<string> archivedFilesToUnzip = archivedFiles
    .Where(name =>
    {
        var match = regex.Match(name); // check the file name for id
        if (match.Success) // id found
        {
            // extract the id from the file name
            var id = match.Groups["id"].Value; 
            return missing.Contains(id); // check if it should be added
        }

        // failed to match pattern for id
        // probably can throw error here to fix the pattern or check the file name
        return false;
    })
    .ToList();

This uses regular expression to extract id from the file name and then search it in the "missing" ids.
Explanation for this particular regular expression can be found @regex101.

+1 for using a hashed set. I was about to post similar logic using query syntax and let id = filename.Split(@'\').Last().Split(@'_').First(), but the idea is the same, so not worth a competing answer. - var archivedFilesToUnzip = (from filename in archivedFiles let id = filename.Split(@'\').Last().Split(@'_').First() where missing.Contains(id) select filename).ToList();

You can try this LINQ query, which returns the expected result:
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

List<string> localPatientsIDs = new List<string>
    { "1550615", "1688", "1760654", "1940629", "34277", "48083" };

List<string> remotePatientsIDs = new List<string>
    { "000-007", "002443", "002446", "214", "34277", "48083" };

List<string> archivedFiles = new List<string>
{
    @"G:\Archive\000-007_20230526175817297.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\002443_20230526183639562.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\002446_20230526183334407.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\14967_20240703150011899.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\214_20231213150003676.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\34277_20230526200048891.zip",
    @"G:\Archive\48083_20240214150011919.zip"
};

// a helper function
var getPatientId = (string input) =>
{
    string pattern = @"\\([^\\_]+)_"; // an appropriate pattern
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
};

var query = from file in archivedFiles
    // elements present in remotePatientsIDs
    where remotePatientsIDs.Contains(getPatientId(file))
          // but not in localPatientsIDs
          && !localPatientsIDs.Contains(getPatientId(file))
    select file;

foreach (var file in query)
    Console.WriteLine(file);


Here's simple LINQ query doing what you want:
var filtered = archivedFiles
    .Where(file => localPatientsIDs.Any(Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith))
    .ToArray();

Here's little break down:

localPatientsIDs.Any(Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith) will check if there are any items in localPatientsIDs matching criteria, which is:

Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith - Path.GetFileName will get the file name from path, StartsWith will check if the file name starts with any element from localPatientsIDs



To make it more clear, I would define such method:
bool FileNameBeginsWithItem(string filePath, IEnumerable<string> prefixes)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    return prefixes.Any(fileName.StartsWith);
}

and then you can use it like this:
var filtered1 = archivedFiles
    .Where(file => FileNameBeginsWithItem(file, localPatientsIDs))
    .ToArray();

var filtered2 = archivedFiles
    .Where(file => FileNameBeginsWithItem(file, remotePatientsIDs))
    .ToArray();

UPDATE
If you want to see if the file name begins with defined prefix followed by _, then use this code:

var filtered = archivedFiles
    .Where(file => localPatientsIDs.Any(x => Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith($"{x}_")))
    .ToArray();

and modified method:
bool FileNameBeginsWithItem(string filePath, IEnumerable<string> prefixes)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    return prefixes.Any(x => fileName.StartsWith($"{x}_"));
}


@fabricioLima note that this can "fail" if you have file with name 2141_... and you need to add only file for id 214 but not 2141. That is the reason why I have not added such solution and went with regexes. Though if you always have fixed ids length (which seems not being the case based on the data) then this is simpler approach.

@guru-stron, now I can see the difference and understand the need for regexes, which were also proposed by dmartinezfernandez. I'll try to implement them. I'm not a professional developer, so it is hard for me to predict the potential failures. That's why this kind of discussion is of major importance to me! Thank you guys!

@GuruStron good point, updated my answer.

@MichałTurczyn upvoted

I would question the efficiency of this approach at scale. If you had 99,000 localPatientsIDs, 100,000, remotePatientsIDs (1,000 missing locally) and 100,000 archivedFiles, how many times would Path.GetFileName() and .StartsWith() be executed?
